# How is scikit-learn cross_val_predict accuracy score calculated?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Does the `cross_val_predict` (see [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html),  v0.18) with *k*-fold method as shown in the code below calculate accuracy for each fold and average them finally or not?

```
cv = KFold(len(labels), n_folds=20)
clf = SVC()
ypred = cross_val_predict(clf, td, labels, cv=cv)
accuracy = accuracy_score(labels, ypred)
print accuracy
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

No, it does not!

According to [cross validation doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) page, `cross_val_predict` does not return any scores but only the labels based on a certain strategy which is described here:

> The function cross_val_predict has a similar interface to
>   cross_val_score, **but returns, for each element in the input, the
>   prediction that was obtained for that element when it was in the test
>   set**. Only cross-validation strategies that assign all elements to a
>   test set exactly once can be used (otherwise, an exception is raised).

And therefore by calling `accuracy_score(labels, ypred)` **you are just calculating accuracy scores of labels predicted by aforementioned particular strategy** compared to the true labels. This again is specified in the same documentation page:

> These prediction can then be used to evaluate the classifier:
>
> ```
> predicted = cross_val_predict(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10) 
> metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, predicted)
> ```
>
> **Note that the result of this computation may be slightly different
>   from those obtained using cross_val_score as the elements are grouped
>   in different ways.**

If you need accuracy scores of different folds you should try:

```
>>> scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv)
>>> scores                                              
array([ 0.96...,  1.  ...,  0.96...,  0.96...,  1.        ])
```

and then for the mean accuracy of all folds use `scores.mean()`:

```
>>> print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
Accuracy: 0.98 (+/- 0.03)
```

---

### How to calculate Cohen kappa coefficient and confusion matrix for each fold?

For calculating `Cohen Kappa coefficient` and confusion matrix I assumed you mean kappa coefficient and confusion matrix between true labels and each fold's predicted labels:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.svm.classes import SVC
from sklearn.metrics.classification import cohen_kappa_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

cv = KFold(len(labels), n_folds=20)
clf = SVC()
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X):
    clf.fit(X[train_index], labels[train_index])
    ypred = clf.predict(X[test_index])
    kappa_score = cohen_kappa_score(labels[test_index], ypred)
    confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(labels[test_index], ypred)
```

---

### What does `cross_val_predict` return?

It uses KFold to split the data to `k` parts and then for `i=1..k` iterations:

- takes `i'th` part as the test data and all other parts as training data
- trains the model with training data (all parts except `i'th`)
- then by using this trained model, predicts labels for `i'th` part (test data)

In each iteration, label of `i'th` part of data gets predicted. In the end cross_val_predict merges all partially predicted labels and returns them as the final result.

This code shows this process step by step:

```
X = np.array([[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])
labels = np.array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'])

cv = KFold(len(labels), n_folds=3)
clf = SVC()
ypred_all = np.chararray((labels.shape))
i = 1
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X):
    print("iteration", i, ":")
    print("train indices:", train_index)
    print("train data:", X[train_index])
    print("test indices:", test_index)
    print("test data:", X[test_index])
    clf.fit(X[train_index], labels[train_index])
    ypred = clf.predict(X[test_index])
    print("predicted labels for data of indices", test_index, "are:", ypred)
    ypred_all[test_index] = ypred
    print("merged predicted labels:", ypred_all)
    i = i+1
    print("=====================================")
y_cross_val_predict = cross_val_predict(clf, X, labels, cv=cv)
print("predicted labels by cross_val_predict:", y_cross_val_predict)
```

The result is:

```
iteration 1 :
train indices: [2 3 4 5]
train data: [[2] [3] [4] [5]]
test indices: [0 1]
test data: [[0] [1]]
predicted labels for data of indices [0 1] are: ['b' 'b']
merged predicted labels: ['b' 'b' '' '' '' '']
=====================================
iteration 2 :
train indices: [0 1 4 5]
train data: [[0] [1] [4] [5]]
test indices: [2 3]
test data: [[2] [3]]
predicted labels for data of indices [2 3] are: ['a' 'b']
merged predicted labels: ['b' 'b' 'a' 'b' '' '']
=====================================
iteration 3 :
train indices: [0 1 2 3]
train data: [[0] [1] [2] [3]]
test indices: [4 5]
test data: [[4] [5]]
predicted labels for data of indices [4 5] are: ['a' 'a']
merged predicted labels: ['b' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'a']
=====================================
predicted labels by cross_val_predict: ['b' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'a']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I got how to calculate `cross_val_score` and average for each fold. Similarly, could you show me how to calculate `Cohen kappa coefficient` and `confusion matrix` for each fold and then average?

Comment: HI. See my update for Cohen kappa coefficient and confusion matrix. What do you mean by `then average`?

Comment: Hi thanks again, I got your edit and understood the matter. I have a last confusion... In my question, `ypred = cross_val_predict(clf, td, labels, cv=cv)` could you explain me how the `ypred` was calculated using layman's language...

Comment: KFold splits the data to k parts and then for i=1..k iterations does this: takes all parts except i'th part as the training data, fits the model with them and then predicts labels for i'th part (test data). In each iteration, label of i'th part of data gets predicted. In the end `cross_val_predict` merges all partially predicted labels and returns them as a whole.

Comment: Still difficult to understand. Could you show it in the similar way as you explained before using EDIT...

Comment: When would one want to use cross_val_predict? cross_val_score already returns the scores of each fold. I would hesitate to use cross_val_predict to output predicted values for the entire period the data covers, say to visualise the predicted values against the true values, since hyperparameters C and gamma have not been tuned via cross validation here. Maybe best to split the data into a training and test set, tune the hyperparameters in the test set with cross validation, and then evaluate the final model with the test set, as per this: https://sadanand-singh.github.io/posts/svmpython/

Comment: @Omid Thank you for the wonderful answer. I am using the code you have provided in the answer. However, I encountered an issue while running this code, where I posted a question that can be found in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895897/how-to-write-cross-validation-in-python Please let me know your thoughts on it. Thank you. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: @EmJ I'm now briefly accessing the internet after a week of ongoing total and nation-wide internet outage caused by the government of Iran. Sorry to see your question is gone, I hope you've found a solution to your problem by now. P.S.: I probably won't be available for an unknown amount of time again.

Comment: How are the two methods doing something different? They both train and test on the k-1 folds in the same way.

Answer (score 8):

As you can see from the code of `cross_val_predict` on [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.18.1/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L302), the function computes for each fold the predictions and concatenates them. The predictions are made based on model learned from other folds.

Here is a combination of your code and the example provided in the code

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, KFold
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:400]
y = diabetes.target[:400]
cv = KFold(n_splits=20)
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
y_pred = cross_val_predict(lasso, X, y, cv=cv)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_pred.astype(int), y.astype(int))

print(accuracy)
# >>> 0.0075
```

Finally, to answer your question: **"No, the accuracy is not averaged for each fold"**

Comment: `the function computes for each fold the predictions and concatenates them.` What do you mean by `concatenates`? What is the retrieved accuracy mean? Seems it mess up everything. How can I calculate accuracy by averaging for each fold?

Comment: I think Omid have explained it quite comprehensively ;)

Answer (score 2):

As it is written in the documenattion [sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) :

> It is not appropriate to pass these predictions into an evaluation
>   metric. Use
>   [cross_validate](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate) to measure generalization error.

Comment: Why is that true though? What is the difference between using cross_val_predict and cross_validate making only the latter suitable for evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an option for a quick and easy answer, above what the previous developers contributed.

If you take micro average of F1 you will essentially be getting the accuracy rate. So for example that would be:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score    

y_pred = cross_val_predict(lm,df,y,cv=5)
precision, recall, fscore, support = score(y, y_pred, average='micro') 
print(fscore)
```

This works mathematically, since the micro average gives you the weighted average of the confusion matrix.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the OP's question regarding the result of the code is **No**.  It just calculates the average over all the predictions returned by `cross_val_predict` regardless of the fold an individual prediction belongs to.  Hence, the warning **not** to, in general, use this method to score a model.  But, for the long answer to the question posed in the OP's title, how to score a model using `cross_val_predict`, read on.

As has been well demonstrated by @Omid, `cross_val_predict` returns the out-of-sample predictions of each element of each fold generated by `KFold.split`; this array of predictions is ordered by fold. On the other hand, `cross_val_score` returns an array of scores for each fold; this array of scores is also ordered by fold. Under the hood, `cross_val_score` just runs `cross_validate`, but restricts scoring to just one scoring method and returns just the scores of the folds, and not all the rich minutia of `cross_validate`.  In order to calculate a (accuracy)score using `cross_val_prdeict`, one needs to score over the folds the out-of-sample predictions as they are assigned to the folds returned by `KFold.split`...

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, cross_val_predict
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, make_scorer

q = np.arange(6)
kq = KFold(n_splits=3)
list(kq.split(q, q))

>>> [(array([2, 3, 4, 5]), array([0, 1])),
>>>  (array([0, 1, 4, 5]), array([2, 3])),
>>>  (array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5]))]
```

In the code above, `KFold.split` returns three tuples, one for each of the `n_splits`. Each tuple holds two arrays each. Each array is a sequence of indexes into the data, the first for the in-sample (train) elements, the second for the out-of-sample (test) elements, a so-called **train / test** spilt.

For each fold, `cross_validate / cross_val_score` fits a model to the in-sample elements then makes predictions over the corresponding out-of-sample elements and finally scores each model based on the predictions and the true values of the out-of-sample elements returning a score, one for each fold.  On the other hand, `cross_val_predict` also fits three models and makes predictions for over each fold, but it simply returns the out-of-sample predictions ordered by fold, i.e., (and with abuse of notation) `[0, 1| 2, 3| 4, 5]`. Continuing, let's first score a model configuration using `cross_val_score`...

```
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=4, n_informative=2,
                       random_state=42, shuffle=False)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
kf = KFold(n_splits=3)

scorer = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, squared=False)
scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=kf, scoring=scorer, n_jobs=5)
print(scores)
print("Mean error using cv_score:", "{:0.5f}".format(scores.mean()))

>>> [25.50144578 28.08988198 12.04946325]
>>> Mean error using cv_score: 21.88026
```

We have found the estimated mean error for the model configuration specified above by averaging over the errors calculated for each fold. Next, let's see how we can score the same model configuration with `cross_val_predict`...

```
rf_preds = cross_val_predict(rf, X, y, cv=kf, n_jobs=5)
print(rf_preds)

>>> [ 35.69694202 -15.59168309 -11.28825143  21.60466429 -31.96562568
>>>   38.77700627 -19.83164343 -24.38676228 -13.72695055  -1.78560192
>>>   34.89912527 -46.0089495   25.0016941  -14.07779504 -41.93602953
>>>  -22.62378198  58.56391394  29.21820121  -1.80628501  -5.11926971
>>>   -6.19392869 -42.01781879 -12.12197396 -28.29172172  27.51992864
>>>  -44.06038966  -5.74855809  25.48187934   4.31608876 -14.08193166
>>>   31.95718759  54.93512694  -3.77541207 -31.71764816 -34.54156106
>>>    3.23757685   3.31396877  31.64161857 -21.82861194  35.5777048
>>>  -27.43229009  35.07735314 -19.79404724  -7.14075063   0.34668447
>>>   25.33268394  -5.65974797 -40.72478199 -13.1132073  -32.31570859
>>>    1.20279636 -41.2647554   62.72557029  42.9298226  -30.25638425
>>>   27.23373331  -8.22833272 -23.86750856 -13.68328394 -33.20953592
>>>  -29.49308561 -38.86304346  34.88313197  65.72332256  27.23373331
>>>  -32.31570859 -20.33812998 -23.33472881  29.56201955 -17.57730738
>>>   11.00481711  25.0217706   -4.71655636  -5.22493376  37.46886883
>>>  -39.41217135 -19.2260896   26.13223673  65.43519148  24.78781493
>>>   11.00481711 -39.98352882  64.40931468 -17.57730738 -37.53827746
>>>  -33.5331878  -20.58164569 -31.36741304  28.4852275  -20.28666836
>>>   77.18589095  23.63780232 -17.57730738  75.09259284  29.62332547
>>>  -39.41217135 -35.8903216   25.45938026 -18.33439858 -18.33439858]
```

`cross_val_predict` has returned the 100 out-of-sample predictions ordered by fold. Now, let's mimic what `cross_validate` does but using the `cross_val_predict` result...

```
scores = np.array([mean_squared_error(y[x[1]], rf_preds[x[1]], squared=False)
                   for x in kf.split(X, y)])
print(scores)
print("Score using cv_rf_preds:", "{:0.5f}".format(np.array(scores).mean()))
    
>>> [25.50144578 28.08988198 12.04946325]
>>> Mean error using cv_rf_preds: 21.88026
```

What have we done? We grabbed the indexes of the out-of-sample elements for each fold, then used these to get the true and predicted values of each of these out-of-sample elements in each fold so each fold can be scored.

*The mean error estimates of the specified model configuration are the **same***.

Essentially, `cross_val_predict` can be seen as an intermediate step used in `cross_validate / cross_val_score`.  Because of design decisions in `scikit-learn` necessary to support parallel fitting of models over the folds, `cross_validate` does not return the out-of-sample predictions along with the fold scores.  So, if we need both the out-of-sample predictions and the scores, and do not want to cross-validate the model twice (`cross_val_predict` for the out-of-sample predictions then `cross_val_scores` for the scores ), we can train with `cross_val_predict` just once, and use its result decomposed over the fold indexes of `Kfold.split` to calculate the fold scores.

By viewing `cross_val_predict` as just an intermediate step in the `cross_validate` process, it highlights the general admonition to **not** score the results of `cross_val_predict` en masse.  These results are useful for many other reasons, but to use them to score a model configuration, more work needs to be done.