# scikit-learn scores are different when using cross_val_predict vs cross_val_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I expected both methods to return rather similar errors, can someone point me to the mistake please?

Calculating RMSE...

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=555, n_estimators=100, max_depth=8)
rf_preds = cross_val_predict(rf, train_, targets, cv=7, n_jobs=7) 
print("RMSE Score using cv preds: {:0.5f}".format(metrics.mean_squared_error(targets, rf_preds, squared=False)))

scores = cross_val_score(rf, train_, targets, cv=7, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=7)
print("RMSE Score using cv_score: {:0.5f}".format(scores.mean() * -1))
```

```
RMSE Score using cv preds: 0.01658
RMSE Score using cv_score: 0.01073
```

Comment: Have you checked out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43613924/5612363

Comment: @Anwarvic thanks for sharing, I have checked it and while I understand the difference between both functions, I still do not understand why there would be different RMSE for same K folds

Comment: According to the [`cross_val_predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html), it says that **" Results can differ from `cross_validate` and `cross_val_score` unless all tests sets have equal size and the metric decomposes over samples.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here, both of which are mentioned in the documentation of [`cross_val_predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html):

> Results can differ from `cross_validate` and `cross_val_score` unless all tests sets have equal size and the metric decomposes over samples.

The first is to make all sets (training and test) the same in both cases, which is not the case in your example. To do so, we need to employ the `kfold` method in order to define our CV folds, and then use these same folds in both cases. Here is an example with dummy data:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, cross_val_predict
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=2000, n_features=4, n_informative=2,
                      random_state=42, shuffle=False)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
kf = KFold(n_splits=5)

rf_preds = cross_val_predict(rf, X, y, cv=kf, n_jobs=5) 
print("RMSE Score using cv preds: {:0.5f}".format(mean_squared_error(y, rf_preds, squared=False)))

scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=kf, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=5)
print("RMSE Score using cv_score: {:0.5f}".format(scores.mean() * -1))
```

The result of the above code snippet (fully reproducible, since we have explicitly set all the necessary random seeds) is:

```
RMSE Score using cv preds: 15.16839
RMSE Score using cv_score: 15.16031
```

So, we can see that the two scores are indeed similar, but still **not identical**.

Why is that? The answer lies in the rather cryptic second part of the quoted sentence above, i.e. the RMSE score does not decompose over samples (to be honest, I don't know any ML score that it does).

In simple words, while `cross_val_predict` computes the RMSE strictly according to its definition, i.e. (pseudocode):

```
RMSE = square_root([(y[1] - y_pred[1])^2 + (y[2] - y_pred[2])^2 + ... + (y[n] - y_pred[n])^2]/n)
```

where `n` is the number of samples, the `cross_val_score` method does not do exactly that; what it does instead is that it computes the RMSE for each one of the `k` CV folds, and then averages these `k` values, i.e. (pseudocode again):

```
RMSE = (RMSE[1] + RMSE[2] + ... + RMSE[k])/k
```

And exactly because the RMSE is not decomposable over the samples, these two values, although close, are **not identical**.

We can actually demonstrate that this is the case indeed, by doing the CV procedure manually and emulating the RMSE calculation as done by `cross_val_score` and described above, i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
RMSE__cv_score = []

for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X):
    rf.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])
    pred = rf.predict(X[val_index])
    err = mean_squared_error(y[val_index], pred, squared=False)
    RMSE__cv_score.append(err)

print("RMSE Score using manual cv_score: {:0.5f}".format(np.mean(RMSE__cv_score)))
```

The result being:

```
RMSE Score using manual cv_score: 15.16031
```

i.e. identical with the one returned by `cross_val_score` above.

So, if we want to be *very* precise, the truth is that the correct RMSE (i.e. calculated exactly according to its definition) is the one returned by `cross_val_predict`; `cross_val_score` returns an approximation of it. But in practice, we often find that the difference is not that significant, so we can also use `cross_val_score` if it is more convenient.

Comment: The same result can be found while use the output of cross_val_predict: print("RMSE Score using cv_rf_preds:\t", "{:0.5f}".format(np.array([mean_squared_error(y[x[1]], rf_preds[x[1]], squared=False) for x in kf.split(X, y)]).mean()))

Comment: @dmbaker I am not sure I am following (or what exactly `kf.split(X,y).mean()` actually returns), but in any case you are very welcome to post an answer, if you think you can add something that has not been adequately covered above.

Comment: The `split` method returns an iterator of tuples of arrays of indexes into the folds of (X, y). Each tuple, one tuple per fold, holds two arrays indexes. The first array has the in-sample/training set of indexes, the second, for the out-of-sample/test set. By iterating over the OOS sets one calculates the score of each fold on the OOS predictions then takes the mean. This is what `cross_val_score` does under-the-hood. `cross_val_predict` returns the OOS predictions ordered by the folds so we can use `split` to decompose the folds.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the good work of @desertnaut...

```
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=4, n_informative=2,
                      random_state=42, shuffle=False)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
kf = KFold(n_splits=3)

rf_preds = cross_val_predict(rf, X, y, cv=kf, n_jobs=5) 
print("RMSE Score using cv preds:\t", "{:0.5f}".format(mean_squared_error(y, rf_preds, squared=False)))

scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=kf, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=5)
print("RMSE Score using cv_score:\t", "{:0.5f}".format(scores.mean() * -1))

print("RMSE Score using cv_rf_preds:\t", "{:0.5f}".format(np.array([mean_squared_error(y[x[1]], rf_preds[x[1]], squared=False) for x in kf.split(X, y)]).mean()))
```

We can see the results are the same as in the loop derived score.

```
RMSE Score using cv preds:       23.00883
RMSE Score using cv_score:       21.88026
RMSE Score using cv_rf_preds:    21.88026
```

For a deeper dive look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77847608/4241746

Accept for very specific cases, `cross_val_precict` is not really meant for scoring.  It can been seen more as an intermediate step, build models and make predictions with the models.  The next step is scoring the models with these predictions and true values.