# Why cross_val_predict returns only single prediction array when cv=5

Tags: scikit-learn

When I run

```
cross_val_predict(a_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
```

I get a single 1d array out of it:

```
array([False, False,  True, ..., False, False, False])
```

Shouldn't there be an array of predictions per fold?

Similar to

```
cross_val_score(a_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
```

returning 5 items array. One score per each fold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cross_val_predict` does ouf-of-fold predictions for the complete dataset that you are interested in. Your dataset is split into `k` folds, the model is trained on k-1 folds and predictions for the hold-out hold is produced and stored for the output.  See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524968/9640384) for more details.